# SQL Server 2008 R2 reindex job reorganise getting stuck

Tags: index, sql-server-2008-r2

I am currently experiencing this job getting stuck in my nightly maintenance solution -

```
ALTER INDEX [PK_ThirdPartySettleCalled] ON [evo_archive].[dbo].[ThirdPartySettleCalled]
 REORGANIZE WITH (LOB_COMPACTION = ON)
```

a full reindex of the table works.

but I'm using Ola Hallengren's awesome solution as I do on a number of sites that need maintenance solutions. http://ola.hallengren.com/Documentation.html and the job gets stuck in the middle of the night.

I've tested it as a single statement from within ssms with the same result, without an error I'm a little short of ideas.

Anyone experienced this issue before ?

No blocking,

the table is circa 300 million rows,

basically I say 'stuck' because no other processes are running in SQL server, and its been reorganising for hours with no error.

It is in the same state with 25% fragmentation or virutually 0% (tested after a full rebuild of the index)

Comment: What does "getting stuck" mean exactly? Did you investigate what the SPID is waiting on by looking at the wait type in sys.dm_exec_requests, checking for blocking, etc.? How big is the table? What is the % of fragmentation before you start the command and after you cancel because it's "stuck"? Did you observe any I/O-related entries in the system event log or SQL Server's log?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand.  sorry, did't add all the things i've looked at and was still frustrated!. Within sql server -  No blocking, the table is circa 300 million rows, basically I say 'stuck' because no other processes are running in SQL server, and its been reorganising for hours with no error.     It is in the same state with 25% fragmentation or virutually 0% (tested after a full rebuild of the index)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved

The problem was we had a rogue cron job (unix job) related to our web servers that was using an incorrect login,

eventually it took up all 8 CPU’s so the reindex job was simply waiting for some CPU to become available before it could continue (this is why the job failed to timeout)